# Pulling data from non sequential rows and adding it to a different sheet in sequential rows

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

I am trying to pull data from a range (A1:A:2000) that has any reference to a keyword, no matter where in the range, and transpose the results to a new sheet in consecutive rows from A1 down.
A good example would be a movie script.

If all the lines to a movie were in Column A of a sheet: 'Full Movie Script' and I wanted JUST the lines from a single person moved to a new sheet: 'Mike's Script'. The original 'Full Movie Script' Sheet may look like this:

```
A1 Mike: Blah Blah Blah
A2 Paul: Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
A3 Jerry: Blah Blah Blah Blah
A4 Mike: Blah
A5 Jerry: Blah Blah Blah  
A6 Mike: ...
```

What I want to do with VBA is move JUST Mike's lines, by using the keyword "Mike", to the new sheet:

Mike's Script

```
A1 Mike: Blah Blah Blah
A2 Mike: Blah
A3 Mike: ...
```

I know I could just use an IF statement in the second page and sort the data But ideally I would like to be able to do this without having to filter and sort to get the output.  I'm exploring options in Visual Basic but figured someone may know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this into an unused cell,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:A$2000)/(LEFT(A$1:A$2000, FIND(":", A$1:A$2000)-1)="mike"), ROW(1:1)))
```

Fill down until you get a `#NUM!` error. When you have it working, move to the destination worksheet and correct the cell ranges to include the original worksheet. Optionally, use an `IFERROR` wrapper to show a zero-length string instead of the worksheet error code.

[image]

Comment: My apologies, the real data I am sorting doesn't actually contain a colon.  The reason I went with the movie scrip analogy was because it helped me explain it the best I could, without sharing sensitive data.  How would you write that formula without FIND for the colon?

Comment: Put `Mike` into an unused cell (e.g. Z99) and replace `LEFT(A$1:A$2000, FIND(":", A$1:A$2000)-1)="mike"` `LEFT(A$1:A$2000, LEN(Z$99))=Z$99`

Comment: @Jeeped, thank you so much! I've been using this formula and it works great! However, I'm needing to pull the formula down to about 500 rows so I can make sure I get all the data brought over from the 1st sheet. But in some cases, there are more or far less than 500 rows that need to come over and having the formulas run when there's not data to pull is a waste of memory and it slows down excel. So here's the next challenge. I want to count how many times "Mike's lines" will be pulled over, BEFORE they do. So is there a way to count how many rows I would have if I pulled the formula down?